# SAP HANA SQL: Prepare statement

Tags: sql, hana

Why can't I execute this query in SAP HANA in SQL console?

```
PREPARE stmt1
FROM select * from (select '12' as a from dummy) t1
where t1.a = ?;
```

Error:

> Could not execute 'PREPARE stmt1 FROM select * from (select '12' as a from dummy) t1 where t1.a = ?' in 3 ms 339 µs . SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "PREPARE": line 1 col 1 (at pos 1)

I need using prepare statement in stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

`PREPARE` simply is not valid SQLScript syntax.
Not sure why you think you have to use this in a stored procedure. 
In SAP HANA stored procedures you can simply write your SQL statements including any variables.
E.g.

```
select * from (select '12' as a from dummy) t1
where t1.a = :variable_name;
```

is technically valid - even though the result is only assigned to the default result set. Typically you would assign the result to a table variable like this:

```
x = select * from (select '12' as a from dummy) t1
where t1.a = :variable_name;
```

All this is of course explained in the [SAP HANA documentation for SQLScript](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.02/en-US).